# State-machine workflow in YouTrack - notify reporter 22 hours after state change, only on weekdays

Tags: workflow, youtrack

Rules:

- After the field "Feedback" changes to **Requested**, meaning feedback is requested, reporters have 24 hours to test
- Notify the reporter only on **weekdays** (if a fix is applied Saturday, the notification should wait to be sent until Tuesday morning, giving them a full 24 hours to review) if they haven't changed "Feedback" to **Confirmed** or **Rejected**
- The notification should be sent **2 hours before** the 24 hour window is up

Problem: **How do I delay sending the notification on a weekday if a fix is applied on Friday or Saturday?**

My attempt:

```
state machine Request feedback from reporter for field Feedback {

    initial state Not needed {
        exit {
            // just a placeholder b/c initial state seems to be mandatory
            message ("You are requesting feedback from the reporter.")
        }
    }

    state Requested {
        in 22 hours[always] do {
            // calculate if this is a weekday
            var dayOfWeek = now.format(#EEEE);
            if ( dayOfWeek != "Sat" || dayOfWeek != "Sun" ) {
                reporter.notify("Two hours left to approve fix for the issue"+ getId( ), "Please review the applied fix for issue and set the Feedback to 'Confirmed' or 'Rejected'.");
            } else {
                // somehow delay the notification?
            }         
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight-forward way here which I see is to add several 'in N hours' rules, which will apply to different variants of current day (like, in 46 hours, if today is 'Tue' (i.e. the issue was moved to this state on Sunday), send a notification, etc).

The other way is to avoid using state machines and switch to scheduled rules, which will check the state and some date field (which is set to 'now' when state is changed to Requested) once an hour and send notifications if required.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using a schedule rule since it is, as far as I know, much simpler to implement.